# Selenuim, how to change the $cdc_ variable in webdriver.Remote

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently working with Selenium Chromedriver Remote using docker

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4445/wd/hub', options=chrome_options)
```

I found this post related to selenium being detected by websites. One the instructions to camouflage selenium is to change the `cdc_` variable on it so it is harder to detect it. I have tried this solution with my local chromedriver and it actually works. I would like to emulate that solution in `webdriver.Remote`

This is the post for the local solution:
[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)